# Bash if statement is wrong

Tags: bash

I have the following Bash code:

```
 while read -a line; do
    if [[ line[2] == $2 ]]; then
        version[n]=${line[1]}
        let n++
    fi
 done <"$file"
```

I know for a fact that there's a line in the file which is suppose to satisfy the if statement. I am not comparing numbers but strings so it's not the problem. What's the problem with my if statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `${line[2]}` there.

`[[` doesn't automatically expand bare words like `((` does.

See:

```
$ line=(a b c)
+ line=(a b c)
$ [[ line[1] = a ]]; echo $?
+ [[ line[1] = a ]]
+ echo 1
1
$ [[ ${line[1]} = a ]]; echo $?
+ [[ b = a ]]
+ echo 1
1
$ [[ ${line[0]} = a ]]; echo $?
+ [[ a = a ]]
+ echo 0
0
$ line=(0 1 2)
+ line=(0 1 2)
$ (( line[1] == 1 )); echo $?
+ ((  line[1] == 1  ))
+ echo 0
0
$ (( line[2] == 1 )); echo $?
+ ((  line[2] == 1  ))
+ echo 1
1
```

---

#### Note:

[[` **does** do bare word expansion when used with integer operations. However given how this actually works I don't like that behavior at all and do not understand why it works the way it does.